# Alterar 2 atributos de um XML com XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Tenho o seguinte XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
-<NewDataSet>
-<xs:schema xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" id="NewDataSet">
  -<xs:element msdata:Locale="" msdata:MainDataTable="INFO" msdata:IsDataSet="true" name="NewDataSet">
    -<xs:complexType>
      -<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        -<xs:element msdata:Locale="" name="INFO">
```

(...)

a) Preciso de alterar a última linha com XSLT para onde se lê name="INFO" ficar name="INFO2" e o seguinte xslt funciona:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xs:element[@name='NewDataSet']/xs:complexType/xs:choice/xs:element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">INFO2</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() != 'name']|*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

b) Agora preciso de fazer uma segunda alteração no resto do ficheiro xml (muito grande) e o seguinte xslt também funciona:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="INFO">
    <INFO2><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></INFO2>
</xsl:template>
```

Mas quando tento juntar as 2 transformações num só ficheiro XSLT dá-me erro (na verdade nem sei como fazer isso)?

Alguém pode dar uma ajuda? Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Se você adicionar o segundo template no primeiro XSLT não dá erro. O que você não deve fazer é simplesmente adicionar esses dois templates no primeiro XSLT, pois há ambiguidade. O primeiro deles copia todos os elementos * e atributos @* e no segundo XSLT há um que copia todos os nós node() (inclui elementos) e atributos @*. Alguns processadores (nem todos - alguns apenas imprimem warning) podem falhar por isto, e se houver elementos com conteúdo de texto ele será perdido.

O XSLT abaixo está correto e deve funcionar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:element[@name='NewDataSet']/xs:complexType/xs:choice/xs:element">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">INFO2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() != 'name']|*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="INFO">
        <INFO2><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></INFO2>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```